# Why does Java use :: for method references instead of .?

Tags: java, methods

I often wonder why Java uses `::` for method references instead of `.`, e.g. why write

```
  System.out::println
```

instead of

```
  System.out.println
```

Of course, one might simply answer: "because the designers decided so". On the other hand, I would have expected the second syntax because the dot is the usual Java syntax for accessing class members.

So is there any known special reason for introducing the new `::` syntax instead of using the existing `.` convention for method references?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is to avoid ambiguity in case if class has (static) member with the same name as method (Java allows that).

It is easy to see from code snippet in [Java tutorial about method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

> Because this lambda expression invokes an existing method, you can use a method reference instead of a lambda expression:
>
> ```
> Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);
> ```

If class `Person` in above snippet would also have member named `compareByAge` (of the type appropriate to pass to `Arrays.sort`), dot notation wouldn't allow to tell whether parameter refers to method or member.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pardon my ignorance: I did not know that member variables and methods were allowed to have the same name. +1

Answer (score 3):

They introduced a new syntax because the behaviour is not the same.

The `.` means that you want to get a reference on the function in order to *invoke* it right after.

When you use method reference (`::`) you want to store a reference on the function but you don't want to *invoke* it right away.

A more practical aspect is how would you differentiate between a public attribute and a method having the same name with the `.` ? You simply can't. With `::` there is no more ambiguity.

Comment: "The . means invoking the function, literally executing it's code." No, the dot means accessing the member. The parentheses mean invoking the function in languages with C-style syntax (like Java).

Comment: @MilesRout Indeed my answer is confusing, I have edited it to better clarify my thoughts.